# Probability of a number in the real line

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, research

I have read that the probability to pick a rational number in the real line is null. My problem is:

If $S$ is a dense set in the real line, what is the probability to pick an element of $S$?

There are references for this type of problems(research papers, books etc.)?

Comment: The main problem is how to define a probability measure in the real line.

Comment: You are more likely to have read the picking a number uniformly at random from the interval $[0,1]$ gives you a probability $1$ of picking an irrational number, and a probability $0$ of picking a rational number.  Both are dense

Comment: I have edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the probability measure and the dense set $S$. Could be $0$, $1$, anywhere in between, or undefined.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{card}{card} \card(\mathbb{Q}) = \card(\mathbb{N}) < \card(\mathbb{R})$. I wonder how one defines the probability here.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, but the probability of randomly choosing a rational number from the reals is zero. $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and the probability of choosing such an element is one.

If you are interested in these things, you should study basic measure theory.

(To make statements about chance you actually need a probability measure, so it's easier to restrict yourself to some interval of finite length.)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, another probability measure in on the real linea is, for fixed $s>1$, $P(X=r)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{r^{-s}}{\zeta(s)}&\mbox{if}&r\in\mathbb{N}\\0&\mbox{if}&r\notin\mathbb{N}\end{array}\right.$

Thus, $P(x\in\mathbb{N})=1$, and $\mathbb{N}$ is indeed a very small topological subset of $\mathbb{R}$.